# How to integrate jersey rest api along with springs mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

Iam new to jersey rest services, i tried adding jersey jax-rs related dependencies in maven pom.xml and also servlet configuration in web.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- rest service mapping -->

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.skoruz.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

pom.xml dependencies are :

```
<!-- jax-rs(jersey) -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
 </dependency>
```

i have a simple java class with @path annotated.

```
package com.skoruz.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class DemoRest {

      @GET
      @Path("/getWelcomeText")
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String sayPlainTextHello(){
          return "Hello Welcome back";
      }

}
```

And when i deploy this jar to glassfish and access the url its throwing me this exception

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/rest/hello/getWelcomeText
```

[image]

It would be great if someone help me out in this, stuck in this from long time.

Comment: Switch your servlet-mappings around... The first mapping is `/` which catches all and that cannot handle the jersey stuff as it is now being handled by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: changes servlet mapping...... but still same problem.

Comment: Have you tried instead of "@Path("/hello")" , using @Path("/rest/hello") ?

Comment: /rest/* is something which is configured in web.xml